# IIS7 URL Rewrite module rule help

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to turn off HTTPS when someone hits the root of my site...

I want

```
https://www.domain.com/
```

to redirect to

```
http://www.domain.com/
```

but I also want..

```
https://www.domain.com/secure.aspx
```

or any other named page not to redirect.

Here's what I have so far but I can't get it to work. I tried a thousand ways, and read all the IIS documentation and examples on this, but I can't come up with the magic formula.

```
<rule name="Redirect Root Only to Non HTTP" stopProcessing="true"> 
   <match url="\.com/$" /> 
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your answer:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close .. except the actual pattern (which matches URL path part only and not domain name). The proper pattern is `^$` which means empty string which will ONLY match domain root hit e.g. `https://www.domain.com/`.

The full rule will be:

```
<rule name="Redirect Root to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```